# Jira Python and Rest Api - update is creating new issues instead of updating

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I am trying to update an existing Jira issue Jira Python module.but every time it creates a new issue.

I see the same behavior with REST API too.

```
    issue = jira.issue(issue_key)

    issue.update(fields={"components": [{"name": "test"}]})
```

Please suggest what could cause this